# How to merge same name column from two different dataframes?

Tags: dataframe, machine-learning, jupyter-notebook, data-science, data-analysis

I have four different datasets. I have merged three of the dataframes correctly. I have same name column in 3rd and 4th dataset. When I merge it with 4th dataset. I am not getting the same name column values in well mannerd way. The user_id is repeating when I merge. I don't want to repeat the user_id. I want to see the value in the del_keys column where it's showing me NaN value rather than it's showing me the value in the last of table. Moreover, I want to merge values of same name column on the basis of their user_id.

[image]

In the above image you can see what kind of problem I am getting.

My expected output will look like. There should not be repeated user_id.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

##### using merge on user_id column

```
import pandas as pd

import numpy as np 

df1 = pd.DataFrame({
    'user_id': [1, 2, 3, 4],
    'del': [1.0, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan]
})


df2 = pd.DataFrame({
    'user_id': [3, 4, 5],
    'del_keys': [1.0, 2.0, 3.0]
})


final=df.merge(df2,on="user_id",how="outer")
```

##### Combine first to get rid of Nan values and then drop duplicates

```
final["del_keys"]=final['del_keys_y'].combine_first(final['del_keys_x'])

final.drop(columns=["del_keys_x","del_keys_y"],inplace=True)

final.drop_duplicates(subset="user_id")
```

Comment: Thank you for providing the perfect solution. It's working now.

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing that you use `pd.concat` to merge the dataframes.
Some dataframes:

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df1 = pd.DataFrame({
    'user_id': [1, 2, 3],
    'del_keys': [1.0, np.nan, np.nan]
})

df2 = pd.DataFrame({
    'user_id': [3, 4, 5],
    'del_keys': [1.0, 2.0, 3.0]
})
```

Merge using `pd.concat`:

```py
df = pd.concat([df1, df2])
>>> user_id del_keys
0   1   1.0
1   2   NaN
2   3   NaN
0   3   1.0
1   4   2.0
2   5   3.0
```

Remove duplicates using [`pd.drop_duplicates`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.drop_duplicates.html):

```py
(
    df
    .sort_values('del_keys')
    .drop_duplicates('user_id', keep='first')
    .sort_values('user_id')
)
>>> user_id del_keys
0   1   1.0
1   2   NaN
0   3   1.0
1   4   2.0
2   5   3.0
```

First, we sort the values by `del_keys` such that all `NaNs` are the bottom of the dataframe. Then we can drop  the duplicates and keep the first occurrence for each `user_id`. Lastly, we can sort again to restore the original order.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. It's working fine though it's removing the duplicate user_id but I am still getting the problem. After concatenatng I am getting the NaN values in rest of columns value

User_id B C D E F G del_keys
487  M 8.6 8.6 11.0 47.0 3.0
488  F 7.3 7.3 673.0 59663.0 6.0
489  M 7.3 7.3 908.0 18284.0 NaN
490  NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN 6.0
491 NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN 10.0
... ... ... ... ... ... ... ...


As above you can see, In actual these columns have the values but when I concatenate it gives NaN.

Comment: Are you sure that these values exist in the first place in any of the dataframes?

Comment: Yes, I am sure about that